# How to Create Timestamp column (Inside Pipeline) in destination SQL database table while migrating data from ADLS to SQL

Tags: sql-server-2008, azure-sql-database, azure-data-lake, azure-data-factory

I am migrating bulk of parquetfiles from **ADLS** to **SQL** database table so inside ForEach i used copy activity and it's copy data successfully for all tables.Now in that every table i have to add add column timestamp so it's gives the **DATE** in that column when that data loaded in that respective table.so what should i do in that pipeline so that in that table one timestamp column gets added and give the **DATE** when data gets loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Use a data flow with a derived column called "timestamp" set to currentTimestamp()